# vertical line in html

Tags: html, signature

I have little confusion in HTML. Please review my HTML code and point me out where is the mistake.

I have searched the web but not know much about HTML. I want HTML signature; I have attached signature file and also my HTML code. I want same signature as I attached in picture:

```html
<html>
<head>


<body>

<table border="0">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0">
<img src="http://www.provendo.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo_email.jpg" alt="Signature" height="80" width="200">
</td>

<td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0">
<hr class="vertical"/>
<hr style="width:1.5px;height:150px; background-color: #FEFEFE;"/>
</td>

<td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0"> 
<p> <b>Raymond Wassengen</b><br>Taknisk, Provendo AS</p>
479 33 600 | 99 5000 27 | raymond@provendo.no|
www.provendo.no |
<br>
Nordre fokserod 13, 3241 Sandefjord



</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a `border-left` rule to the `td` that hold the information on the right.  I have added it in the code below.

```
<html>
<head>


<body>

<table border="0">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0">
<img src="http://www.provendo.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo_email.jpg" alt="Signature" height="80" width="200">
</td>

<td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0">
<hr class="vertical"/>
<hr style="width:1.5px;height:150px; background-color: #FEFEFE;"/>
</td>

<td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0;border-left:solid 1px #ED7500;"> 
<p> <b>Raymond Wassengen</b><br>Taknisk, Provendo AS</p>
479 33 600 | 99 5000 27 | raymond@provendo.no|
www.provendo.no |
<br>
Nordre fokserod 13, 3241 Sandefjord



</table>

</body>
</html>
```